# using jQuery to traverse the DOM

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal, jquery-traversing

Given the following html DOM:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <input data-id="somevalue">
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="">edit</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the edit is clicked, I'd like to get the `somevalue`.

A) Would I use `.parent().parent().find()` or is there a more appropriate solution?
B) How would I get the value for the `data-select`? I know how to get it by ID or class but not clear on the syntax to use for data attributes.

Using the following:

`var id = $(this).parent().parent().find().attr('id');

console.log(id);`

outputs `undefined` so I'm not sure if I have a traversing issue or if I don't have the syntax correct for getting the data attribute value.

Comment: Ask yourself .. `find()` what? https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: I was so focused on the traversing that I forgot what I was looking for! :duh!: That's why it's good to another another set of eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$(this).parent().prev().children().data('id')
```

:

```js
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(
    $(this).parent().prev().children().data('id')
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
        <input data-id="somevalue">
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="">edit</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your `.find()`, with no arguments, isn't giving you any results because you didn't pass it any selector to find. Also, the *attribute* isn't `id` - the attribute is `data-id`, so you should use `data('id')` rather than `attr('id')`.

Comment: I thought attr() and data() were essentially the same thing, are they not?

Comment: In your example, you left off `.find()` - was that a typo or intentional?

Comment: Similar, but not the same. `data()` extracts a *data attribute* - that is, an attribute whose name starts with `data-`. But `attr` extracts *a generic attribute*. For example, you could have done `.attr('data-id')`, but `data('id')` is more appropriate.

Comment: I didn't use `.find` because there was no need to use it - press "Run code snippet". No need to find an element when you already know exactly where it is

Comment: Regarding `data` and `attr`, I understand what you are saying but I'll need to dig deeper into that. At least now I know I need to look into this deeper so right there is a lesson learned today! :D

Comment: Regarding my comment about the `find()`, I had a brainfart. I knew that. :rolleyes: